# Developing ASP.NET WCF Service that uses oAuth as the authentication provider

Tags: asp.net, ios, wcf, rest, oauth

I am developing an iOS application that needs to talk to a web server backend. My intention is to develop web services using ASP.NET WCF.

On the iOS side I am using RESTKit to access the web services.

I have read many many different articles, and questions here on stack overflow, and struggled to find a definitive answer to my needs. I can imagine this is quite a common scenario, so I thought I would post a question to clarify this issue for both me and anyone else with this problem.

I need to authenticate the request between the iOS app and the ASP.NET services, and oAuth seems a good way to go. At first I started reading into oAuth 2 Legged, and managed to get a working implementation  by following this tutorial - http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/523/oauth-dot-net (I followed the second option in this tutorial).

This worked great but provided me with no way to know which user the request was on behalf of. I then realised that maybe standard 3 legged oAuth was for me.

I stumbled upon DevDefined.OAuth.WCF and DotNetOpenAuth. Both seem to be lacking in comprehensive documentation.

I tried to follow along with the DotNetOpenAuth provider example, but am struggling to understand how it works.

So my questions:

Does anybody know of a good explanation of setting up an oAuth provider using ASP.NET, and securing WCF web services using oAuth.

Am I going about this the right way, is oAuth for me?

How will oAuth work when the iOS app and server are both coded by me? I dont want the user to have to grant access to this app. It should be automatic when they enter there login details.

I really appreciate any time anyone can put aside to help me with this! It has been driving me crazy for a couple of weeks.

Thanks and Best Regards
Matthew Casey

PS. Sorry about any mistakes in posting to Stack Overflow. Havent posted here before!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jack about .net stuff, but I'm currently looking at implementing a REST webservices for our own trusted iOS app.

Decided that we would have our app collect the user's username/password directly.
Then we implemented a special endpoint that is essentially the first get_request_token call (with all the appropriate headers/signatures/etc).  This allows us to verify the api_key and app_secret (from verifying the signature).  This call will then directly return an access_token.  (skipping a step in the regular 3 legged flow)  This access_token would be tied to the user and have all the standard properties of a regular access_token.

I guess it's a variant of a 2 legged oauth, but I think it's much cleaner

happy to go into more details if you need it.